# How to search for changesets in Gerrit than need to be rebased?

Tags: gerrit

In our [Gerrit installation](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/) (2.8.1-2-g724b796) I'd like to search for changesets of mine that cannot be merged, but must be rebased.  For example, [this change](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/114734/) has "Can Merge" as "No" and would need a manual rebase.

Is there a search syntax to find those changes?  Do our administrators need to set up an extra label or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your currently running 2.8 version, this is not possible.

Gerrit 2.9 brings the `is:mergeable` search operator ([docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#is), [change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/51998)), which should allow you to search for exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

On versions up to 2.8, there's no way to do this with a search parameter:

https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/user-search.html

On version 2.9+, there's a new `is:mergeable` search parameter:

https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#is